# Ocelot QoS doesn't break circuit when n number of exception arises

Tags: microservices, circuit, ocelot

I am carrying out a PoC on **Ocelot Gateway** to use for our microservices architecture. I have successfully used the Gateway to perform all the routing tasks uptil now.

It provides a QoS Service that helds configuration in ocelot.json for circuit breaker and breaks the circuit for a duration.

The configurations set in my **ocelot.json** file are as follows for a specific route:

```
{
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/classes/exception/{id}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/classes/exception/{id}",
      "ServiceName": "class-service",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ],
      "LoadBalancerOptions": {
        "Type": "LeastConnection"
      },
      "QoSOptions": {
        "ExceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking": 2,
        "DurationOfBreak": 10000,
        "TimeoutValue": 3000
      }
    }
```

Now, this works fine for the timeout issue, it breaks the circuit for 10s when the route does not respond in 3s.

But for the exception case, it does not break the circuit when there is an exception arising for 2 times when the route is being called.

Are there any more configurations required?

I have added **Nuget Package for Ocelot and Ocelot.Provider.Polly** and also added the following in my **Startup.cs** file:

```
 s.AddOcelot().AddPolly();
```

Please help me through this.
I have followed the [Ocelot Documentation] https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/qualityofservice.html to implement this

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I had to customize the QoS options provided by Ocelot and create my own circuit breaker policy.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this problem ?